# How to insert attachment using transient variable

Tags: visualforce, javascript, attachment, viewstate, apexinputfile

I am using the `transient` keyword to allow users to upload files greater than 135kb (viewstate limit) on a VF page however since the `transient` keyword doesn't transmit the attachment past the view state, when inserting the attachment, the filename and body is missing.

I set `setRedirect` to false in the Apex class when users navigate to the next page in the form.

Is there a way to upload files greater than the viewstate limit using transient?

Apex

```
public without sharing class AWF_FormClass {
    
    public Application__c app {
        get{
            if(app == null)
                app = new Application__c();
            return app;
        }
        set;
    }
    
    public Transient Attachment ID {
        get {
            if(ID == null)
                ID = new Attachment();
            return ID;
        }
        set;
    }
    
    public Transient Attachment Diploma{
        get{
            if(Diploma == null)
                Diploma = new Attachment();
            return Diploma;
        }
        set;
    }
    
    public AWF_FormClass(){
        
        //Empty constructor
    }
    
    
    
    public PageReference step4(){
            
        PageReference pageRef3;
        PageRef3 = Page.AWF_Employment;
        PageRef3.setRedirect(false);
        if(ID.Name == null){
        ApexPages.addMessage(
        new ApexPages.Message(
        ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,
        'You must upload a copy of your New York State ID to proceed.'
        )
     );
        return null;
        }
        return Page.AWF_Employment;
    }
    
    
    public pageReference saveApplication(){
        try {     
            
        upsert app;
        ID.ParentId = app.Id;
        Diploma.ParentId = app.Id;
        insert ID;
        insert Diploma;
        return Page.AWF_Success;  
            
        } catch(DMLException e){
            Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.SEVERITY.FATAL, 'No such combination exists'));    
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

VF

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="AWF_FormClass" standardStylesheets="false">
    
    <head>
    <link rel = "icon" href = "{!URLFOR($Resource.BCATLogo)}" type = "image/x-icon"/>
    <apex:slds ></apex:slds>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.AWF_FormStyle)}"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>
    
    <br/>
    <div class="center">
    <apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.BCATLogo)}" width="200" height="50"></apex:image>
    <br/>   
    <br/>
    <p class="slds-text-heading_large">2021 Adult Enrollment Form</p>
        
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Personal<br/>Information</li>
        <li>Professional <br/>Background</li>
        <li>Application</li>
        <li>Submit</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    
    <p class="heading">Identification Vertification</p>    
        <apex:form styleClass="fsWrapper">
        <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
        <div class="step1">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Please upload a copy of your New York State ID below:"></apex:outputLabel>
            <br/>  
        <div align="center" style="margin-left: 400px">  
         <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
        </div>
            <br/>
            <div align="center">
             <apex:inputfile value="{!ID.Body}" fileName="{!ID.Name}"></apex:inputfile>
            </div>
        </div> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >
                <div id="sldsbutton" align="center" draggable="false">
                    <apex:commandbutton action="{!step4}" value="Next" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_destructive"></apex:commandbutton>
                </div>  
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Add your vf markup as well?

Comment: Added VF above @MohithShrivastava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Setters are not called when using the `transient` keyword and hence you may be seeing null in the body or title or any other fields.

You can revert back to the non-transient version

```
 public Attachment attachmentRec {
    get {
        if(attachmentRec == null)
            attachmentRec = new Attachment();
        return attachmentRec;
    }
    set;
}
```

Just make sure that you nullify the body after you insert the attachment to clear ViewState for the blob. The pseudo-code is below

```
public pageReference saveApplication(){
    try {     
        
    upsert app;
    attachmentRec.ParentId = app.Id;
    Diploma.ParentId = app.Id;
    insert attachmentRec;
    // Clear this value so view state is saved
    attachmentRec.body = null;
    insert Diploma;
    return Page.AWF_Success;  
        
    } catch(DMLException e){
        Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.SEVERITY.FATAL, 'No such combination exists'));   
       attachmentRec.body = null; 
    }
    return null;
}
```

Notice I changed the variable for Attachment record from `ID` to `attachmentRec`

**Some thoughts on implementation**

1. `Attachments` are outdated and do not have advanced security compared to [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm). Hence use ContentVersion to store files.
2. You can get away with the view state problem by using pure JavaScript and not using Visualforce Markups like Inputfile.

Use a JavaScript library like [jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/) to do this work for you. Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/douglascayers/9316ac7badf990fbe4c31bd68448a040)

Comment: Thanks Mohith. However the error is thrown when the user advances to the next page since the view state limit is being reached in the `step4()` method. The `saveApplication` method is only called at the end of the form on a different VF page.  

So the trick is including the attachment to the new `Application__c` record without exceeding the view state